# Importing dll - using add reference doesn't allow me to use the 'using' function in the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I am using Visual Studio 2017, to create a c# class library (.dll).
I am modding a game and need to import the games .dll files.
I create my project, and add the dll files as a reference, and have checked the local copy box.  Once done however I cannot seem to use them?

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
```

What should be happening (as far as I know) is that I should be able to use the classes within the dll files I am 'using', however the second line of code (Unity Engine, a dll I have added as a reference) is greyed out while the system one is not.

I have looked online but all the answers I have found are for C++, and reference a 'linker' file which I do not know how to implement.

Comment: greyed out - means that you not using any type from that namespace in this file. Do you ever try to compile?

Comment: If it's greyed out, vasily is correct. If it's causing a compile error, remember that dll name != namespace. Are you sure that you are trying to use the correct namespace?

Comment: Have you actually tried to use the classes available in the dll or have you just stopped here?  If that line is Grey (unused) and not Red (invalid), try writing a function using the classes you expect to be available and then update your question if it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

directly inherit the class name like this "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager". If your facing problem by adding namespace.